# Can the Python bool() function raise an exception for an invalid argument?

Tags: python, exception, boolean

It's possible for functions like `int()` or `float()` to raise an exception (`ValueError`) if the argument can't be converted to the appropriate numeric type.  Hence, it's generally good practice to enclose these in a `try-except` if there's a possibility of an invalid argument being passed to them.

But with Python's flexibility when it comes to "truthiness," I can't think of any possible value you might pass to the `bool()` function that would raise an exception.  Even if you call it with no argument at all, the function completes and returns `False`.

Am I correct that `bool()` just won't raise an exception, as long as you pass it no more than one argument?  And as a result, there's no point in enclosing the call in a `try-except`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`bool` complains when `__bool__` does not return `True` or `False`.

```
>>> class BoolFail:
...     def __bool__(self):
...         return 'bogus'
... 
>>> bool(BoolFail())
[...]
TypeError: __bool__ should return bool, returned str
```

No builtin types are this insane, though.

[DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) made a very valuable comment: the popular [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) library has examples where `bool` will produce an error.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1],[2]])
>>> bool(a)
[...]
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

[user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) pointed out the following corner case.

> Standard, near-universal stdlib example for things like this: a weakref.proxy to a dead object will raise a ReferenceError for almost any operation, including `bool`.

```
>>> import weakref
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> bool(weakref.proxy(Foo()))
[...]
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

This is not unique to `bool`, any function that uses its dead argument might throw this error, for example `myfunc = lambda x: print(x)`.

Comment: Or a type could be explicitly designed so it can't be converted to a `bool`, raising an exception in `__bool__()`.

Comment: @kindall sure. I can't think of any example in the standard library though.

Comment: While not stdlib, numpy arrays are a good real-world example of objects in common use which often raise ValueErrors on bool calls.

Comment: @DSM, interesting and helpful point, given that the ordinary `list` type will evaluate `True` so long as it's non-empty.

Comment: Standard, near-universal stdlib example for things like this: a weakref.proxy to a dead object will raise a ReferenceError for almost any operation, [including `bool`](https://ideone.com/H8lP7L).

Comment: @user2357112 thanks, I added your comment to the answer for visibility.