# Is it possible for `__contains__` to return non-boolean value?

Tags: python

The documentation says that `__contains__` *should* return true if item is in self, false otherwise. However, if the method returns a non-boolean value `x`, it seems that python automatically converts it to `bool(x)`.

Is there any way to avoid that, and return the actual value `x`? Or is this feature behavior implemented directly in the interpreter and there's no way to change this?

Comment: protocols are there for something, I think that you cannot and that you should not do that. There are many options for not doing so and still achieve the same.

Comment: I think you are out of luck. You could return a value that has an overridden `__bool__` method, except that `bool` will throw an error if `__bool__` does not return `True` or `False` ...

Comment: @Netwave: however, my question is about the "cannot" part. Protocols can be violated if the object is used inside a single codebase, and this enhances readability

Comment: @timgeb: thanks, I was afraid of that. So, is `bool` called automatically on the result?

Comment: There's also the issue of what to do in your case if `x` isn't present. Do you return `False`, in which case how do you tell the difference between finding `False` and failure? Do you raise an exception, which would be quite surprising for a function that is expected to have a proper return value in the event of failure?

Comment: @all: thanks for all the great answers, too bad I can only accept one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__bool__` is indeed being called on the return value of `__contains__`.

Consider the following classes:

```
class BoolWithPrint:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __bool__(self):
        print("Im being booled.")
        return self.value

class StrangeContains:
    def __contains__(self, x):
        return BoolWithPrint(x)
```

... which behave like this:

```
>>> True in StrangeContains()
Im being booled.
True
>>> False in StrangeContains()
Im being booled.
False
>>> 'stuff' in StrangeContains()
Im being booled.
[...]
TypeError: __bool__ should return bool, returned str
```

So as far as I know, you are out of luck. You could sneakily override `__bool__` on the value `__contains__` returns, but that will only delay the `TypeError` because `__bool__` must return `True` or `False`.

For additional context, see [Can the Python bool() function raise an exception for an invalid argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862526/can-the-python-bool-function-raise-an-exception-for-an-invalid-argument).

Answer (score 10):

Note that it's not `__contains__` that converts the value to a Boolean, but the `in` operator that *calls* `__contains__`. With

```
class Foo(list):
    def __contains__(self, v):
        if super().__contains__(v):
            return v
        else:
            return False

>>> f = Foo([1,2,3])
>>> f.__contains__(2)
2
>>> 2 in f
True
```

Answer (score 6):

A `foo in bar` will be compiled to `COMPARE_OP (in)` for CPython3. The implementation uses `PySequence_Contain()` and then [coerces](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/621cebe81b1e6c8de10425955bf532d31ee4df42/Python/ceval.c#L4772) to result to a `bool`. So while you *could* return something else, you [always](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/621cebe81b1e6c8de10425955bf532d31ee4df42/Python/ceval.c#L4772) end up with a bool after the call.

Comment: Not quite the most right, since it only discusses one particular implementation. @zvone's answer provides a quote the specifies how `in` uses the return value of `__contains__` regardless of implementation.

Answer (score 5):

In Python documentation, section [6.10.2. Membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) says:

> For user-defined classes which define the [`__contains__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) method, `x in y`
>   returns `True` if `y.__contains__(x)` returns a true value, and `False`
>   otherwise.

So clearly, if you return a non-bool, the `in` operator will still return a boolean.

If you directly call `__contains__`, then of course you will get whatever result is returned from it.

For example:

```
class X:
    def __contains__(self, other):
        return 11

x = X()

8 in x  #  True

x.__contains__(8)  # 11
```