# The attempt to terminate a function in a thread using signals fails in PyQt6

Tags: python, multithreading, signals-slots, qthread, pyqt6

I have a time-consuming thread operation, but it cannot emit progress during the processing. So, I use another thread to simulate its progress. When the time-consuming operation is completed, it emits an end signal and simultaneously signals the end of the simulation process. However, the actual function operation in the simulated thread is not controlled. In the example below, `self.thread_two_stop_signal.emit()`, however, `handle_two()` is still running.

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt6.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QThread
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QProgressBar, QPushButton


class ThreadOne(QObject):
    done_signal = pyqtSignal()
    finished_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(100):
            time.sleep(0.01)
        self.done_signal.emit()

    def finished(self):
        self.finished_signal.emit()


class ThreadTwo(QObject):
    finished_signal = pyqtSignal()
    progress_signal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        self.if_finished = False
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            if self.if_finished or i == 99:
                self.progress_signal.emit(i)
                return
            i += 1
            self.progress_signal.emit(i)
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def finished(self):
        self.finished_signal.emit()

    def reset(self):
        self.if_finished = False

    def stop(self):
        print("stop")
        self.if_finished = True


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    thread_one_do_signal = pyqtSignal()
    thread_one_finished_signal = pyqtSignal()

    thread_two_do_signal = pyqtSignal()
    thread_two_reset_signal = pyqtSignal()
    thread_two_stop_signal = pyqtSignal()
    thread_two_finished_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My PyQt6 App")

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 200)

        self.btn = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.btn.setGeometry(150, 25, 50, 50)

        self.bar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.bar.setGeometry(50, 100, 300, 20)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.start)

        self.proxy_thread_one = QThread()
        self.thread_one = ThreadOne()
        self.thread_one.moveToThread(self.proxy_thread_one)

        self.thread_one_do_signal.connect(self.thread_one.run)
        self.thread_one_finished_signal.connect(self.thread_one.finished)

        self.thread_one.done_signal.connect(self.handle_one)
        self.thread_one.finished_signal.connect(self.proxy_thread_one.quit)
        self.thread_one.finished_signal.connect(self.proxy_thread_one.wait)

        self.proxy_thread_two = QThread()
        self.thread_two = ThreadTwo()
        self.thread_two.moveToThread(self.proxy_thread_two)

        self.thread_two_do_signal.connect(self.thread_two.run)
        self.thread_two_stop_signal.connect(self.thread_two.stop)
        self.thread_two_reset_signal.connect(self.thread_two.reset)
        self.thread_two_finished_signal.connect(self.thread_two.finished)

        self.thread_two.progress_signal.connect(self.handle_two)
        self.thread_two.finished_signal.connect(self.proxy_thread_two.quit)
        self.thread_two.finished_signal.connect(self.proxy_thread_two.wait)

    def start(self):
        self.proxy_thread_one.start()
        self.proxy_thread_two.start()

        self.thread_one_do_signal.emit()
        self.thread_two_reset_signal.emit()
        self.thread_two_do_signal.emit()

    def handle_one(self):
        self.thread_two_stop_signal.emit()  
        self.thread_two_finished_signal.emit()
        self.thread_one_finished_signal.emit() 
        self.bar.setValue(100)

    def handle_two(self, value):
        self.bar.setValue(value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    main_window = MainWindow()  
    main_window.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

After I disconnect the singal, it started working.

```
    def handle_one(self):
        self.thread_two.progress_signal.disconnect(self.handle_two)
        self.thread_two_stop_signal.emit()
        self.thread_two_finished_signal.emit()
        self.thread_one_finished_signal.emit()
        self.bar.setValue(100)
```

I want to understand why my previous approach didn't work and if there is a solution for it.

Additionally, I would like to inquire about my usage of threads in PyQt6. Is my approach correct? Can it exit gracefully? Are there any potential thread safety issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with the example is that it uses blocking loops within each thread, which will prevent immediate processing of thread-local events.

When a signal is emitted across threads, an event will be posted to the event-loop of the receiving thread. But if a blocking loop is being executed within the receiving worker thread, it will freeze event-processing in exactly the same way as it would within the main GUI thread. So steps must be taken to explictly enforce prcessing of such thread-local events. The simplest way to achieve this is to call `QApplication.processEvents()`, like so:

```
class ThreadTwo(QObject):
    ...
    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            QApplication.processEvents()
            if self.if_finished or i == 99:
                self.progress_signal.emit(i)
                return
            ...
```

As for the more general question of whether threads are used "correctly" in the example: this is largely a matter of opinion/taste. The problem mentioned above could be completely by-passed by removing most of the custom signals and calling `stop()` directly instead. Strictly speaking, this would mean that modifying the `if_finished` attribute was no longer thread-safe - but given that only one thread ever needs to read the value of `if_finished`, this would make no measurable difference to the reliability of the code. In fact, it could be argued that the resulting simplification would make the code easier to understand and maintain, and thus *qualitatively* more reliable in that sense. To give some idea of how such code might look, try the re-written example bewlow:

```
import sys, random

from PyQt6.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QThread
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QProgressBar, QPushButton,
    QWidget, QHBoxLayout,
    )


class WorkerOne(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def run(self):
        delay = random.randint(25, 50)
        for i in range(100):
            QThread.msleep(delay)
        self.finished.emit()


class WorkerTwo(QObject):
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        self._stopped = False
        for i in range(1, 101):
            QThread.msleep(50)
            if not self._stopped:
                self.progress.emit(i)
            else:
                self.progress.emit(100)
                break

    def stop(self):
        print('stop')
        self._stopped = True


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My PyQt6 App")
        self.setGeometry(600, 200, 400, 50)
        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(widget)
        self.btn = QPushButton("Start")
        self.bar = QProgressBar()
        layout.addWidget(self.bar)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.start)

        self.thread_one = QThread()
        self.worker_one = WorkerOne()
        self.worker_one.moveToThread(self.thread_one)
        self.thread_one.started.connect(self.worker_one.run)
        self.worker_one.finished.connect(self.handle_finished)

        self.thread_two = QThread()
        self.worker_two = WorkerTwo()
        self.worker_two.moveToThread(self.thread_two)
        self.thread_two.started.connect(self.worker_two.run)
        self.worker_two.progress.connect(self.bar.setValue)

    def start(self):
        if not (self.thread_one.isRunning() or
                self.thread_two.isRunning()):
            self.thread_one.start()
            self.thread_two.start()

    def handle_finished(self):
        self.worker_two.stop()
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.thread_one.quit()
        self.thread_two.quit()
        self.thread_one.wait()
        self.thread_two.wait()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.reset()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: 1. Note that (on pyside2 at least + windows 11...) calling `QApplication.processEvents()` too many times in a short span of time will potentially create a lot of lag on the application while also emiting a signal to the main thread. I solved this by calling processEvents every 0.1s or so, using a way to measure elapsed time in code. 2. Shouldn't `self._stopped` be protected by a QMutex in this case? I understand that _in this case in particular_, even if garbage is written to self._stopped, it would possibly read it as True instead of False. But even so, discarding a mutex... A risky move imo.

Comment: (1) But `processEvents` only looks at the event-queue of the ***calling thread***, which in the example code will remain completely empty until the stop-signal is received. It will never create any lag, since it's not being invoked in the main GUI thread. (2) There is no real risk of any kind, since only one thread ever reads the `stopped` flag and it's always set to the same immutable value. Even if dozens of threads called `stop()` multiple times, it could never make any difference to the reliability of the code (thus, practicality definitely beats purity in this particular scenario).

Comment: 1. Sorry, xy problem in my own particular case. 2. I still think that mutexes are necessary. There are times that even the bool() function can [raise exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52862551/14956120). Also, each value in python is internally a class. Take int for example, in the IDE it prints "<class 'int'>". So, if threads attempt to read and write values on a single shared variable, I think that we cannot discard the possibility that one thread will write incomplete data to that variable, and the other one may read garbage.

Comment: (2) Python is [strongly typed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11328920/984421) and doesn't have variables (i.e. pointer references) as such, so there's never any possibilty of corrupting data in the way you suggest. That fact isn't changed by user-defined classes that use documented protocols to customise behaviour. It is never possible to change the ***type*** of a "variable" in Python; all you can ever do is assign objects to names. Multithreading does not affect these basic language guarantees in any way. Thread-safety is concerned with *program logic*, not data corruption.